# Trying to load Spinner position / value causes crash at Integer.parseInt()

Tags: android, spinner

Beginner at android programming here. I am writing an app that has a settings page for gender/height/weight and this information is computed and passed to another activity (Main activity).

When the user goes back to the settings page, it will load all the values that user has input before. Currently no problem loading for my EditText fields, but the gender is using a Spinner (male/female) and the Settings activity just crashes when I input the code for it.

It seems to be crashing at Integer.parseInt().

Thanks in advance!

**Snippet from button listener**

```
btnSave = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
.
.
.
savePreferences("storedAge", inputAge.getText().toString());
savePreferences("storedHeight", inputHeight.getText().toString());
savePreferences("storedWeight", inputWeight.getText().toString());
savePreferences("storedBMR", String.valueOf(myBMR));


int userChoice = chooseGender.getSelectedItemPosition();
savePreferences("storedGender",Integer.toString(userChoice));
```

**savePreferences**

```
private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();
}
```

**loadPreferences**

```
private void loadSavedPreferences(){
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


String age = sharedPreferences.getString("storedAge", "");
inputAge.setText(age);

String weight = sharedPreferences.getString("storedWeight", "");
inputWeight.setText(weight);
String height = sharedPreferences.getString("storedHeight", "");
inputHeight.setText(height);
String gender = sharedPreferences.getString("storedGender", "");
Integer genderValue = Integer.parseInt(gender);
chooseGender.setSelection(genderValue);
}
```

Tried Amit's suggestion but still getting a crash. Log cat as below:

```
01-31 13:43:29.576: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
01-31 13:43:30.158: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf08b0 that was originally bound here
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf08b0 that was originally bound here
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-31 13:43:54.516: E/ActivityThread(609):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609): null
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf08b0 that was originally bound here
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-31 13:43:54.526: E/StrictMode(609):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce27f0 that was originally bound here
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce27f0 that was originally bound here
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-31 13:43:54.546: E/ActivityThread(609):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609): null
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce27f0 that was originally bound here
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-31 13:43:54.567: E/StrictMode(609):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before parsing "gender" String to Integer, check if it is not null or blank and then repalce your **setSelection()** line with this-

```
if (gender != null && gender.length() > 0) 
        {
            Integer genderValue = Integer.parseInt(gender);
            chooseGender.setSelection(genderValue, true);
        }
```

Comment: just tried it, still crashes, this time the whole application as opposed to just the activity.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too sure on how to check, but will paste log cat error above

Comment: @altern4te Are you testing it on emulator device? if yes, then delete this current emulator device and make a new emulator device and then run your code.

Comment: I tried both emulator and my mobile phone. Both crashes.